# download file on client-side sent in response of API

Tags: c#, asp.net, api

I have a task to download whatever file is sent in the response of my API call, Possible extensions are zip, pdf and doc. I just have the API endpoints to download those files returned in the response, no idea about server side code.

The task is not to write or create those files on server and then transmit to local, but need to download it directly on the client side.

I have written a web method which calls the API on click of button and gets the response stream, the code written also downloads the required file correctly , but those downloaded files never open. they are either corrupted or damaged.

Below is my code to download and write the file on client side.

Any idea what is possibly going wrong, or how can i download the files correctly.

Note: This aren't very large files, the max size possibly could be 50Mb or so.

Not sure, what all things from stack overflow i have tried so far, but no luck was for sure.

```
    public string CallService(string hbno)
    {
        try
        {
            var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("URL");
            httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
            httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
            DataTable dt = GetPrintLogData(hbno);
            if (dt != null && dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
                {
                    string json = _Serializer.Serialize(body);
                    streamWriter.Write(json);
                    streamWriter.Flush();
                    streamWriter.Close();
                }
                System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
                using (var resp = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse())
                {
                    using (var stream = resp.GetResponseStream())
                    {
                        if (resp.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                        {
                            var cd = new ContentDisposition(resp.Headers["Content-Disposition"]);
                            StreamToFileAttachment(stream, cd.FileName);
                            return "successful";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            return "Something went wrong";
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else { return "No match found in database"; }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

```
        public static byte[] ReadFully2(Stream stream)
        {
            try
            {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[32768]; //set the size of your buffer (chunk)
                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream()) //You need a db connection instead
                {
                    while (true) //loop to the end of the file
                    {
                        int read = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length); //read each chunk
                        if (read <= 0)
                        {
                            var test = ms.ToArray().Length;
                            //check for end of file
                            return ms.ToArray();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            ms.Write(buffer, 0, read); //write chunk to [wherever]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                //throw;
            }
        }
```

```
    static void StreamToFileAttachment(Stream str, string fileName)
    {
        try
        {
            System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
            var length = ReadFully2(str).Length;
            byte[] buf = new byte[length];  //declare arraysize
            str.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length);
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", length.ToString());
            HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = GetMimeTypeByFileName(fileName);
            HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream.Write(buf, 0, buf.Length);
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush(); // Sends all currently buffered output to the client.
            HttpContext.Current.Response.SuppressContent = true;  // Gets or sets a value indicating whether to send HTTP content to the client.
            HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest(); // Causes ASP.NET to bypass all events and filtering in the HTTP pipeline chain of execution and directly execute the EndRequest event.

            // HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            //throw;
        }
    }
```

Comment: why closing streamwriter inside a using? what is `body` that you get json from? What is `ReadFully2` ? Why do you read the stream once for length in `ReadFully2` (but never use it) and once into a byte[] usign a length from ReadFully wich you do not show? Maybe you read a stream twice? What means "corrupt" when recieving? Empty? Filled but not openable? I do not see any code to open whatever was received?

Comment: Hi Patrick, the code is a bit messy since i have been trying a multiple things so far, Read fully 2 is a method i later implemented to read the entire stream, earlier i was just reading the part of the stream, by corrupt i mean, the file has data size when created (zip and pdf) but when i try to extract or open pdf it gives error saying it cannot be loaded for pdf and for zip it is "cannot open files as archive"